# Asp.net web app slowness (huge base class issue ?)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance, base-class

Asp.net web application having 100+ webpages. All pages are inheriting a baseclass. 95% of the methods are based on ajax.

The baseclass contains almost 50% of ajax methods and rest methods are in individual pages.

App is slow at different times. DB side there is no slowness. SP are optimized.

App becomes slow mainly while loading, sometimes if it is 25 records or it is 5 records. Only the ajax calls are there during loading. Sometimes it loads faster, sometimes it is not and gets browser message page recovering.

Looking for suggestions to find the issue.

Session is disabled, using windows authentication.
Debug is false
Viewstate is false

Comment: There are just too many potential variables. Have you checked the web server CPU and memory utilizations? Have you checked the network connectivity between client and web server and between web server and database server?

Comment: Checked the CPU and memory utilization, everything seems normal. Need to check on the network connectivity between the client and webserver and webserver and database server.